# Restore file in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cp

Is there anyway to restore replaced file in Ubuntu?
The file was replaced using cp command.
I tried finding answer but couldn't find anyone. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file was overwritten with another file (by copying over it), there would be no direct way to recover it.

A fully correct answer will depend on the filesystem and storage you are using. Ubuntu itself is not equipped to recover contents that is lost in that manner.

I suggest to turn to backups (other copies of the file, an original source on the internet or your own memory).

Comment: if that indeed answers your question, could you mark the answer as "accepted"? Open questions are treated special in StackOverflow...